# IR Remote button being recognised by ir-keytable but not by irw

Tags: 12.10, remote, lirc

I am having a strange problem where one button on my media center remote is not being recognised by `irw`. I have it setup to receive ir-keytable scans via *devinput*.

I have had the same environment working before, only thing that has changed is a format of the `/` partition.

`ir-keytable -t` successfully recognises the button as *KEY_ENTER 0x001c* and in lirc's devinput map the button is successfully listed as *KEY_ENTER 28*

Does any body know where I should be looking? Additional information can be provided.

Comment: beanaroo Can you let me know what your LIRC config is? I'm trying to get the same remote working with everything. I'm actually doing it on a RPI, but it'similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had a conflicting program: `inputlirc`

After removing it, reconfiguring lirc, rebooting, reconfiguring ir-keytables, everything seemed to be working.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge inputlirc
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure lirc
$ sudo reboot now
$ sudo ir-keytables -c -w /etc/rc_keymaps/rc6_mce
```

`irw` shows no problems.

```
$ sudo irw
000000008001006c 00 KEY_DOWN devinput
000000008001001c 00 KEY_ENTER devinput
000000008001006f 00 KEY_DELETE devinput
```

To make the effect permanent, I have to edit */etc/rc.local*

```
/etc/init.d/lirc stop
/usr/bin/ir-keytable -c
/usr/bin/ir-keytable -w /etc/rc_keymaps/rc6_mce
/etc/init.d/lirc start
```